# (node:12068) electron: Failed to load URL: app://-/ with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (-6)'

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I tried to implement a feature of previewing statics websites (html, css, js files) which consists of uploading folders that contain them, save it and preview the static website in a new window after clicking a button. And I used for that purpose electron-serve library, but I got that error after running the app and simulating the process:

> (node:12068) electron: Failed to load URL: app://-/ with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
> (Use `electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:12068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (-6) loading 'app://-/'
> at rejectAndCleanup (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7510)
> at EventEmitter.failListener (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7723)
> at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:527:28)
> (node:12068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> [12068:1117/094334.336:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(689)] Message 3 rejected by interface blink.mojom.Widget
> [12068:1117/094334.339:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(689)] Message 6 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost[12068:1117/094334.339:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(689)] Message 7 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost

here is my main.js file's code

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView, ipcMain, protocol } = require("electron");
const serve = require('electron-serve');
const path = require("path");
const url = require('url');
const isDiv = process.eventNames.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const isMac = process.platform === "darwin";
let loadURL = serve({ directory : path.join(__dirname, "./compressedFolder") });

let mainWindow;
// let view;

// create main window
function createMainWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    icon: path.join(__dirname, "src/img/greenieweb.icns"),
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    minHeight: 600,
    minWidth: 1000,
    webPreferences: {
      title: "GreenieWeb",
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "/src/preload/preload.js"),
      devTools: true /*Disables Devtools*/,
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  // open dev tools if in dev env
  if (isDiv) {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }

  ipcMain.on('app-topreview-loaded', async (event) => {
    const previewWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      parent: mainWindow,
      show: false,
      width: 1200,
      height: 800,
      minHeight: 600,
      minWidth: 1000,
      webPreferences: {
        title: "Preview",
      },
    })
    await loadURL(previewWindow);
    previewWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        previewWindow.show()
      })
  })
  // load main html file
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));
}

// App is ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // create the main window
  createMainWindow();

  // Disable menu
  // Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);

  // remove mainwindow from memory on close
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  // create window if none is created when app is active
  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createMainWindow();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the renderer.js code :

```
let previewBtn = document.getElementById("preview-btn");


const fs = versions.fs;


let gFRWRPCounter = 0;
let isEmptyDir = true


previewBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(!isEmptyDir){
        removeFolderFromDir()
    }
    addFolderToThePlace()
    
    window.electronAPI.showWebApp()
})

function removeFolderFromDir(){
    fs.rmSync('./compressedFolder', { recursive: true, force: true });
    fs.mkdir("./compressedFolder", (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("Something went wrong")
        }
    })
    isEmptyDir = true;
    gFRWRPCounter = 0;
}

async function addFolderToThePlace(){
    if(directoryHandle===undefined){
        new Notification(emptyFolderNOTIFICATION_TITLE, {
            body: emptyFolderNOTIFICATION_BODY,
        }).show();
        return;
    }
    for await (const file of getFilesRecursivelyWithRP("", directoryHandle)) {
        const content = await file.text()
        await fs.mkdir(
            "./compressedFolder" + file.relativePath,
            { recursive: true },
            (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    fs.writeFileSync(
                        "./compressedFolder" + file.relativePath + "/" + file.name,
                        content
                    );
                }
            }
        );
    }
    isEmptyDir = false
}


async function* getFilesRecursivelyWithRP(fPath, entry) {
    if (entry.kind === "file") {
        const file = await entry.getFile();
        if (file !== null) {
            file.relativePath = fPath;
            yield file;
        }
    } else if (entry.kind === "directory") {
        let nFPath = "";
        if(gFRWRPCounter>0){
            nFPath = fPath + "/" + entry.name;
        }else{
            nFPath = fPath
            gFRWRPCounter++;
        }
        for await (const handle of entry.values()) {
            yield* getFilesRecursivelyWithRP(nFPath, handle);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the preload.js code :

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
const fs = require('fs')

// this is just an example
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("versions", {
  fs: fs,
});

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  showWebApp: () => ipcRenderer.send('app-topreview-loaded')
})
```

What my code is doing is to upload a folder which it will be previewed, into a folder in my project's folder called compressedFolder, and after that the event 'app-topreview-loaded' is triggered a new window containing the preview of the folder is shown, but what I get is a blank window. What I understood from that error is that when the  'serve({ directory : path.join(__dirname, "./compressedFolder") })' is called the folder is being empty at that time, so I have to find a method that enable me to reexecute the function 'serve({ directory : path.join(__dirname, "./compressedFolder") })' when the event 'app-topreview-loaded' is triggered, because its after that time that the folder is filled with the static files, but when I put it inside the ipcMain.on it generates an other error which says that that function should be invoked before the app is ready.
Any Help please on how I can solve that problem.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question. In particular, please add a [mcve] so we can reproduce the error. It seems that something in your app is trying to navigate to `app://-/`. Since this string is not present in the code you shared, it can only be present in the renderer process' code.

Comment: I think that I have added the minimal reproducible example.